# How to find out duplicated code on Mac?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

I need to find out all duplicated code in a xCode project,

I have found some similar tools on windows like: CCFinder (http://www.ccfinder.net/ccfinderxos.html), or CloneTracker (http://cs.mcgill.ca/~swevo/clonetracker/). but none of them works on Mac.

Is there any similar tools for Mac?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think this maybe late but there are a number of clone detection tool that you can use on Mac.such as

1 -   http://homepage.usask.ca/~mdu535/tools.html
which is a text-based clone detector.

2 -  http://www.txl.ca/nicaddownload.html

I hope this helps.